# electric field at charged metallic surface

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, conductors

Inside a charged metallic object in equilibrium, the electric field vanishes. Just outside the object, the field is finite. So far, so good.

Now, I just read in a book that the value of the field *at* the surface is *half* its value infinitesimally *off* the surface.

I had never seen this statement, and I don't trust this book. My question is whether the statement is sound.

I include a picture from the book that makes more clear what the author means.

[image]

Comment: I think the author of the book is attempting some "regularization" of the discontinuity, maybe thinking of the charge density as a delta function and then using that the integral of "half" delta is 1/2, or something like this, but I am not sure it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Just outside the surface of the conductor, it behaves like an infinitely charged sheet. Hence the Electric field is halved. You can refer to the case of Electric Field due to an infinitely large charged sheet to get a better picture.